# MVVMLight - Messaging, is it possible to decouple lifetimes of the sender & receiver?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

When using the Messenger class in MVVMLight it requires the a minimum of two endpoints (sender and receivers) to be in existence and setup (registered in the case of receiver) before a message is sent.

What I would like is the ability to break this coupling, so at registration I can declare I want to be notified of the last message sent on a topic.

(Laurent) is this possible at the moment?

If not I take it I could derive off Messenger and implement this my self?

Comment: How about a messaging bus (e.g. XMPP, NServiceBus, RabbitMQ, etc..) as the decoupling agent. Have the receiver just send messages over the other buses.

Comment: have you read the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wrote one and provided it as part of the [WP7Contrib](http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/), it can be found in the Messaging project.